# Can window films be fully removed from a window?

Tags: home, cooling, insulation, thermal-regulation, renting

I live in the Pacific Northwest which has seen some [serious heat waves](https://www.climate.gov/news-features/event-tracker/preliminary-analysis-concludes-pacific-northwest-heat-wave-was-1000-year) this summer, so now I'm looking for more ways to keep cool. Aside from air-conditioning, I'm interested in passive techniques to improve indoor comfort, so I am considering the possibility of adding of insulating window films on some south-facing windows to reduce indoor daytime temperatures in the summer.

But I am living as a renter in a single-family detached home, which means I'm not supposed to make any permanent changes, especially to the outside of the house. That means I can only install window films if I'm sure it's possible to remove them later on.

So **is it possible to fully remove a window film** after it has been installed for years, or is it permanently attached to the window? If removal is attempted, does it leave a trace or residue on the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window film [can be removed](https://www.fabglassandmirror.com/blog/how-to-remove-old-window-tint-or-window-film-from-glass/), but it takes some effort.

The film needs to be softened with ammonia, heated with a blow dryer & carefully peeled from the one of the corners. A razor blade could be useful.

After the film has been removed the window needs to be thoroughly cleaned to remove the adhesive.